# Event Handler for Updating Combo Box when clicked but not from code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox

### **The Problem**

I'm trying to update one combo box based on another one's input. For now I've been using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to detect when a new item has been selected from the list. This issue, however is that when I try and make the paired Combo Box equal to a value when there's only one option, it triggers the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, which causes the two events to throw back indefinitely.

### **The Research**

I've looked through the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox_events(v=vs.110).aspx), however I couldn't find anything besides the `SelectedIndexChanged` and `SelectedValueChanged`

### **The Question**

Is there a way for me to prevent an event from triggering via code, or to raise an event only when the user has clicked on the input of a Combo Box and not when the value is changed by code?

Comment: No, events are always triggered. Why not simply check, if the values/indices of both ComboBoxes are equal and stop running the method then?

Comment: What do you mean? The Combo Boxes come in pairs. So if say one is selected "S" the other should become "H". However the issue is that when I make the other "H" it triggers the event again and something weird happens where they just alternate until it I get a Stack Overflow Exception.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. That's why I made the proposal that you just query, if the value is the corresponding one and if so, you return from the method (`Exit Sub`).

Comment: set a flag or remove the event handler when you are changing the selection from code and dont want the event to run